# Wire Compatibility

Tags: electrical

I am installing a new oven.  The old oven was wired with a pig tail connection to a 220 receptacle.  The new oven is to be hard wired.  The existing wiring appears to be 6 gauge wire and the wiring for the new oven appears to be 12 gauge.  Can 6 gauge and 12 gauge wire be connected with a wire connector?

Comment: They can be connected, but 12 gauge sounds small for an oven. An oven typically requires a 30A or 40A circuit. 12 gauge is typically only up to 20A. What is the oven model?

Comment: Is it gas with an electric broiler or something?

Comment: So the old over was connected with a flexible power cord plugged into a receptacle. You say the new oven is to be hard wired, but do the instructions for the new oven state it must be hard wired? Do the instructions allow for the use of a cord with a plug and does the local code allow it? If this is a "built in" oven, then I can see why a plug might not be allowed. The connection will be hidden in normal use and a plug could somehow get loose and make a hot connection.

Comment: To make a hard wired connection I suppose one removes the 240 V receptacle and connects the proper sized wire with approved connectors to the wires in the box. There would be a special cover plate that would fit on the opening of the box and would have a strain relief to mechanically secure the cable.

Comment: All new oven that I know of come with installation instructions. What do the installation instructions say? All wire nuts and other wire connection devices have a maximum and minimum wire connection size, they should be listed on the package.

Answer (score 1):

### With the correct connector, yes

While the largest wire nuts are barely capable of handling 1 6AWG wire, there are connectors for larger wires out there, known as *insulated multitap connectors*, that can be used to readily make an insulated splice or tap in larger wire sizes -- the smallest size they are generally available in can accept anywhere from 14AWG to 4AWG wire, and they use setscrews torqued down with a torque screwdriver (or inch-pound torque wrench, for larger sizes) to make the connection.  (Sometimes they're called "Polaris connectors" but that's a brand name; also, the product depicted is for illustration purposes only.)

[image: insulated multitap connector]